# Adding TXT dns record to which

Tags: wordpress, dns, web-hosting, cloudflare, google-search-console

Hi my website has domain registrar at crazydomain and web hosting at siteground, and connected to cloudflare. If I want to add txt dns record for google search console. where should I add the record ? domain registrar, web hosting, or cloudflare ?

Comment: This entirely depends on where your DNS records are located, look at your current DNS for an SOA or Name Server.

Comment: I guess I should add to the domain name provider (domain registrar) not web hosting (siteground) but there is no option to add txt type record on my domain registrar (crazydomain)

Comment: Go to this website.  https://www.ultratools.com/tools/dnsLookup put in your domain name, and post in your question what the NS is... Then someone can answer you.

Comment: the NS is cloudflare

Answer (score 0):

You've answered your own question.  Since your Name Server is cloudflare.  Add the DNS record for `TXT` there.